# Module skin css file not included when merging

Tags: layout, css

When I disabled CSS merge files in Magento 1.9.0 , my css extension's css file is successfully being loaded to the head. But when I enable css meging, it won't merge my css file content to the generated merge css file.

Anyone has any idea ?

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="test.variables" template="ext/test/variables.phtml"/>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/ext/test/test.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="test.libraries" template="ext/test/libraries.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

In overal my module is 100% functional without css merging. I chcked caching and similar things.

Comment: just some thoughts: did you clear your css cache? did you check that your file might be included, but in a wrong order and be overwritten by other css?

Comment: @Claudiu yes all checked

Comment: Anyone ????????